# Getting map function with custom CanBuildFrom and Builder to work in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have a Builder making a String out of an Int:

```
  class MyBuilder extends LazyBuilder[Int, String]
  {
    def result: String = "value: " + Int.toString
  }
```

And this CanBuildFrom implementation:

```
  class IntToStringCanBuildFrom extends CanBuildFrom[Set[Int], Int, String]
  {
    def apply(from: Set[Int]) = this.apply()
    def apply() : MyBuilder = new MyBuilder
  }
```

And I want to use it in the following example:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3)
val result = list.map(2*)(new IntToStringCanBuildFrom)
```

But I get a compile error:

```
- type mismatch; found : Test.IntToStringCanBuildFrom required: 
 scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[List[Int],Int,?]
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here? How to make this work? Obviously it doesn't like the fact my CanBuildFrom implementation has a String type param but I thought this was supposed to be the way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things to change in your code to do this:

- First, you `CanBuildFrom` is defined to work for `Set[Int]` as input but you give it a `List[Int]` (which is not a `Set`!). So it should be, for example, `CanBuildFrom[Seq[Int], Int, String]`. Since a `List` is a `Seq`, it will work.
- Then, your lazy builder needs to actually do something with the elements it received. It exposes a `protected var parts: ListBuffer[TraversableOnce[Int]]` that contains everything that was added into it. Let's just print its content:

  ```
  class MyBuilder extends LazyBuilder[Int, String] {
    def result: String = "value: " + parts.flatten.mkString(",")
  }
  ```

  Then, your `CanBuildFrom` can create that builder when called:

  ```
  class IntSeqToStringCanBuildFrom extends CanBuildFrom[Seq[Int], Int, String] {
    def apply(from: Seq[Int]): Builder[Int, String] = apply()
    def apply(): Builder[Int, String] = new MyBuilder
  }
  ```
- Finally, you can use it directly:

  ```
  scala> val list = List(1, 2, 3)
  list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

  scala> val result = list.map(2 * _)(new IntSeqToStringCanBuildFrom)
  result: String = value: 2,4,6
  ```

  or indirectly through an implicit in scope:

  ```
  scala> implicit val intSeqCanBuildFrom = new IntSeqToStringCanBuildFrom
  intSeqCanBuildFrom: IntSeqToStringCanBuildFrom = IntSeqToStringCanBuildFrom@52cc537d

  scala> val result: String = list.map(2 * _)
  result: String = value: 2,4,6
  ```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how I missed the fact it was a set and not a seq or list. However your result shows the string as a single item, but I wanted to transform every single Int into a String, so in this example create "value: 2", "value: 4" and "value: 6". How would I go about that?

Comment: I am not sure I get you: you want one `String` for each `Int`, so you want, for example, a `Seq[String]` as output? But then, `list.map(s => "value: " + s)` is enough and there is no need for a `CanBuildFrom`. What collection type do you want to produce using your `CanBuildFrom`?

Comment: Yeah I know this isn't a great example, this isn't a real world situation, I was just trying to understand the matter.

I originally thought it would work in a way that the builder was called for each element but like you said, it's getting the entire parts ListBuffer and I have to generate my own Seq from that. So now I have a `class MyBuilder extends LazyBuilder[Int, Seq[String]]` and a `class IntToStringCanBuildFrom extends CanBuildFrom[Seq[Int], Int, Seq[String]]` and that seems to get me what I wanted.